# Can't match a hex sequence with std::regex and :xdigit:

Tags: regex, c++11

I have this code:

```
try
{
    std::string input = "00179d006d000174";

    std::regex pattern("[[:xdigit:]]{16}");

    if(std::regex_match(input, pattern))
        std::cout << "Full match" << std::endl;
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

But can't understand two things:

- why does it throw a *regex_error*
- if I add the std::regex::basic flag to the the regex it no longer throws the error but still doesn't print "full match"
- how would I match a simple sequence of 16 hex digits like the one in the example?

Comment: What is the GCC  version (`gcc --version`)?

Comment: gcc version is 4.8.4

Comment: Please consider upgrading.